# Connection reset by peer when hitting Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm having a problem, where I can't send network requests to a Docker container I've created. I've exposed the correct ports, so I'm not sure what other issues could be at fault here.

I have a server running in container `alice` at `localhost:10009`:

```sh
$ docker exec -it alice bash
bash-4.4# curl localhost:10009
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Port 10009 is exposed from my container:

```sh
$ docker port alice 
10009/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:10009
```

When doing the same `curl` from my host machine I get a different message:

```sh
$ curl localhost:10009
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I get the same result when using both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. Updated my question

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I would check to see if the server application is configured to only listen to requests coming from its "localhost", this check depends on the type of server that you're using which is not mentioned.

an easy check is to start your container as follows:

```
docker run --network host -d yourimagename
```

You don't need to worry about port mapping since you're using the `host` network

then try to curl, if that works, then you'll just need to review your server listening IP setting.

```
curl localhost:10009
```

Answer (score 30):

I think there are some problems with @Bouzid Zitouni's answer, according to   [Docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#goal):

> this is the same level of isolation as if the nginx process were running directly on the Docker host and not in a container

However, if you use the `--network host` you will not have isolated networking in the container, and the `host` networking driver only works on Linux hosts.

The problem of Connection refused/reset happens because your Server is listening on 127.0.0.1 inside the container and the port forwarding is going to external IP of the container (e.g. 172.17.0.2).

**Solution**

In your case you need to run a new container making your server to listen on all interfaces. Example using python `http.server` :

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -it python:3.7-slim python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

**Note**

The option `--bind 0.0.0.0` it's specific option of `http.server`. Probally your server has other ways to specify this.

**References:**

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Answer (score 17):

I would like to expand on @Bouzid Zitouni's answer. It seems there is indeed an issue with the address(es) the server binds to.

*Connection reset by peer* usually indicates that one has defined a port mapping for the container that does not point to a listening server. Here is an example to illustrate this:

```
docker run -p 10009:10009 -it ubuntu bash
```

Install `nmap` in container:

```
apt-get update && apt install -y nmap
```

Run `ncat` **(localhost only)**

```
# ncat -v --listen localhost 10009
...
Ncat: Listening on 127.0.0.1:10009
```

Run `curl` on host:

```
# curl localhost:10009
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

You actually get the same result even if you don't have any server process at all.

Run `ncat` **(all IPs)**

```
# ncat -v --listen 10009
...
Ncat: Listening on :::10009
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:10009
```

`Curl` on host connects successfully. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error with the docker container running locally on my machine/laptop.

I ran multiple containers and was using the same port number say 8080 for each container run.

After killing all docker process and restarting docker i am now able to connect to the container on the mentioned port 8080 in my case.

```
$ sudo service docker stop
Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:
  docker.socket
$ sudo service docker start
```

Comment: Just confront the same issue, and restart docker server resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

For those using a docker-compose.yml file, including `network_mode: "host"` worked for me. Such as:

```
app:
    ...
    command: sh -c "npm start --host"
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    network_mode: "host"
```

Now I can access on http://127.0.0.1:5173/