# Container works but localhost says unable to connect

Tags: docker

Hi I have made my flask app and I have exposed port 5001 in Docker file.
I pushed it to dockerhub repo and ran on different machine by

```
docker container run --name XYZ <username>/<repo_name>:<tag>
```

The log says that app is running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/

But if I open that localtion in browser its says

```
Unable to connect
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get -y install python3.8 \
    && apt -y install python3-pip \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt 

EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT  ["python3"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: The details are a little sparse here, but if you want to expose 5001, you'll probably need the -p command. i.e. -p 5001:5001

Comment: host port has to be opened

Comment: Try running flask with `--host=0.0.0.0` or `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')`. Also check that the container is active/healthy using `docker ps`.

Comment: If it says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000` that sounds very similar to [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues); you both need the `host=0.0.0.0` option @Daniser suggests and also the `-p` option from @JesseQ.

Comment: @Daniser, What does `0.0.0.0`. Does Host ip: `0.0.0.0` means anyone on internet can use my flask app ?

Comment: @DavidMaze, same question, What does 0.0.0.0. Does Host ip: 0.0.0.0 means anyone on internet can use my flask app ?

Comment: In order for anyone on the internet to see your app you will have to configure your home router to support this using port forwarding (the app will have your **public IP**). But setting the host IP to `0.0.0.0` will allow anyone in your LAN (e.g: connected to your router at home) to see your app by connecting to the **private IP** of your computer (private IP inside the LAN).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze and @Daniser `host=0.0.0.0` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the port. Try this:

```
docker run container -p 5001:5001 --network host --name XYZ <username>/<repo_name>:<tag>
```

Comment: Now its shows a different error. Its says the connection was reset.

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile also?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773604/connection-reset-by-peer-when-when-hitting-docker-container) for connection reset

Comment: @Piyush just added Docker file in original question

Comment: just updated my answer. Hopefully it will work

Comment: I tried still shows 
`the connection was reset`

Comment: add --network host flag too.

Comment: `--network host` generally disables Docker's networking stack (you should get a warning that that `-p` option is ignored; it will also break standard communication between containers).  It's definitely not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the port mapping for your container then only port will exposed outisde

```
docker container run --name XYZ -p 5001:5001
<username>/<repo_name>:<tag>
```

And then if it's Docker hub windows then you can directly hit with above local host url else you need to docker machine ip address and hit with that ip like below command
docker-machine ip